# how to save pdf inside controller and pass pdf patch

Tags: laravel, dompdf

pdf api -> https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

I create some simple API, everyone who pass some data will recaive link to pdf file.

The thing is, i dont know how to save pdf after conroller make changes inside my blade template.

so...

i already try changing data by request and that was working.

something like :

```
class pdfGenerator extends Controller
{
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->json()->all(); 
    return view('test2', compact('data'));
}
}
```

that work well, also pdf creator works well from web.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('test2');
  return $pdf->download('test2.pdf');
});
```

that one just download my pdf file as expected.

but, now i try to pust some changes from request and save file but... without efford... any idea?
My code after tray to save content

```
class pdfGenerator extends Controller
{
public function show(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->json()->all();

    return $pdf = PDF::loadView('test2', compact('data'))->save('/pdf_saved/my_test_file.pdf');

}
}
```

But i get only some errors. Please help :D

Comment: It could be helpful to know which PDF library are you using

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: So you want to save and download the file? what about changing the last line? `return PDF::loadView('test2', compact('data'))->save('/pdf_saved/my_test_file.pdf')->download('my_test_file.pdf');`, actually you are returning true or false because you are returning the result of the variable $pdf assignation

Answer (score 0):

How can I save a PDF inside my controller and pass the PDF patch?

```
$data = $request->json()->all();

$pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('test2', $data);

return $pdf->download('test2.pdf');
```